# What is the "MSN Game API"?

Tags: microsoft

The other day I herd this "MSN Game API" mentioned, but I can not find any information about it anywhere. This particular API seems to be for browser based games (Such as Flash, and ActiveX embedded games).

What exactly is this API for? And is that its correct name? is it to do with the [MSN Zone](http://zone.msn.com)? Where can I find more information about it, and maybe even some documentation on the actual API.

Comment: If only I could time travel back 6 years and warm him...

Comment: I never did end up using it haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API in question is, I believe, the MSN Games GDK for developing games for the MSN Games portal (or Live Messenger). The SDK itself is not readily available to the public; I believe you need to contact developer support to get it. Check out [this page](http://zone.msn.com/en/microsoftcasualgames/submit.htm) at the MS Casual Games portal.